# Android to PC File sharing by using common WiFi network

Tags: android, file-upload, wifi, file-sharing

I am currently developing the android application in which I have to upload a file (any normal document) from my android device to any other PC/laptop. But this should be done only with the use of any common WiFi network. (Use of Internet connection or WiFi-Direct functionality is not allowed.)

So my question is how to share files from android device to PC/laptop by using only common WiFi network ?

I think xender does the same thing for android to android device.
But I have to do it for android device to PC/laptop.

Comment: Dear  Randyka Yudhistira. can you elaborate please ?

Comment: make a webservice using java or php. host it in your PC, make a method to accept file transfer request from your android

Comment: And how to send request to host with our Android device ?

Comment: Using HttpPost with multipart to send file

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **Socket** for it. The PC can be server, and the phone can be client. Then connect them. After that, you can send the thing you want by sending *byte[]* in android socket.

By the way, if you can use a USB line to connect PC with phone, you can try *LocalSocket* in android and *adb forward* in PC.